# How to install packages from com.intellij for IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I installed IntelliJ IDEA and trying to create a GUI application with it. But code that automatically being genereted actively uses classes and packages from com.intellij. For example com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridLayoutManager. But there is no such package in my project and it is not in the list when I trying to download it from Maven repository. How should I add it?
[image]

Comment: According to a quick google search that package is in `forms_rt`.

Answer (score 1):

These packages are coming from the `forms_rt` JAR located in the `<IDEA_Installation_Directory>\libs` directory.

Add it to the module dependencies as described here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html

or via `pom.xml` / `build.gradle` if the project is Maven / Gradle based.